# Replace multiple strings in document field for all Mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I have this code:

```
db.Collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.content = doc.content.replace('old', 'new'); 
  db.Collection.save(doc);
});
```

It works fine, but it replace only the first string from document field. My goal is to replace all strings:

```
content: 'old old old'
```

to

```
content:'new new new'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just seconds after posting, i solved with regex:

```
db.Collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.content = doc.content.replace(/\old/g, 'new'); 
  db.Collection.save(doc);
});
```